# Excel vba UserForm TextBox add new line

Tags: vba, excel

I have UserForm with ProgressBar and TextBoxes in it. TextBoxes are updated during code execution, but it doesn't add new line as it is supposed to do:

```
 UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value & "Opened file " & i & Chr(13)
```

I tried also `vbNewLine` and `vbCrLf` with the same result: it just show this [image] symbol instead of putting text on the next line.

How to fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547268/vba-textbox-new-next-line set multiline to true?

Comment: @anotherfred, That solved it, thanks. Suggest an answer and I'll approve it.